# PHP: Adding text to a file

Tags: php, arrays, file

I'm trying to set up authentication on my server, however, I know little about Php.

I have a php file filled with users and passwords:

```
 function getPassword( $user )
 {
    // the user/password database. For very small groups
    // of users, you may just get away with expanding this
    // array.
    $passwords= array (
        'user1' => 'password1',
        'user2' => 'password2',
        'user3' => 'password3',
        'user4' => 'password4'
         );
    $password = $passwords[ $user ];
    if ( NULL == $password )
        return NULL;
```

Without manually editing the array of passwords, I want a php file to read in user inputs for usernames and passwords and append it to the array.

I have a vague idea of how this could work by looking up documentation:

```
<?php
function fwrite_stream($fp, $string) {
    $fp = fopen('shit.php', 'w');
    for ($written = 0; $written < strlen($string); $written += $fwrite) {
        $fwrite = fwrite($fp, substr($string, $written));
        if ($fwrite === false) {
            return $written;
        }
    }
    return $written;
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

How do I tell this to write to the array?

Comment: EDIT: Actually, i think what I'm doing is wrong. The function I should probably use is: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: You should not store the password in plain text but just a hash of it (see [`crypt`](http://php.net/crypt) for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not hardcode the list of usernames and passwords in your PHP script. I would instead do something like this for reading the array from disk:

```
// Web server must have read permission for the file,
// but it should be placed outside of public_html
// for security reasons.
$gPasswordFile = '/home/kevin/password.db';

// Read the password file's entire contents as a string.
$contents = file_get_contents($gPasswordFile);

// Unserialize the file's contents, assuming an empty array
// if the file does not exist.
$passwords = $contents ? unserialize($contents) : array();
```

For writing the array to disk:

```
file_put_contents($gPasswordFile, serialize($contents)) or die('Could not save password file!');
```

If you were to have thousands of users as on a public web site, it would be inefficient to load the entire user database for every attempted login. Then you would likely turn to a real DBMS such as MySQL to store the information.

(As a side note, you really should be hashing passwords with a per-user salt to limit the effect of a password file compromise. Save that for another question though.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly recommend against what you're trying to do now. Why not store the passwords in a separate file, and have the script read/write that? Manipulating PHP in this way is asking for trouble, as you'll need to keep in mind every kind of input your users may throw at it.

I think your best bet is `file_put_contents('filename.txt', "\"$username\",\"$password\\n" FILE_APPEND);` (of course, you'll have to apply escaping and/or validation on the username/password)

Then get the contents with `$passwords = fgetcsv('filename.txt')`